# How can i do it with stored procedure in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I' calculating distance between coordinates gradualy executing this queries.

1. 

```
     /*insert into tmp11(select * from clients_lite where inwork > 0 limit(5000));*/
```

2.

```
     select *, cast(ATAN(SQRT(power((COS(tmp11.lat*PI()/180)*SIN(city.lon1*PI()/180-tmp11.lon*PI()/180)),2)+power((COS(city.lat1*PI()/180)
                  *SIN(tmp11.lat*PI()/180)-SIN(city.lat1*PI()/180)*COS(tmp11.lat*PI()/180)*COS(city.lon1*PI()/180-tmp11.lon*PI()/180)),2))/
                  (SIN(city.lat1*PI()/180)*SIN(tmp11.lat*PI()/180)+COS(city.lat1*PI()/180)*COS(tmp11.lat*PI()/180)*COS(city.lon1*PI()/180-tmp11.lon*PI()/180)))*6372795 as int) as distance
    into dist
    from tmp11 
    inner join  city
    on cast(ATAN(SQRT(power((COS(tmp11.lat*PI()/180)*SIN(city.lon1*PI()/180-tmp11.lon*PI()/180)),2)+power((COS(city.lat1*PI()/180)
                  *SIN(tmp11.lat*PI()/180)-SIN(city.lat1*PI()/180)*COS(tmp11.lat*PI()/180)*COS(city.lon1*PI()/180-tmp11.lon*PI()/180)),2))/
                  (SIN(city.lat1*PI()/180)*SIN(tmp11.lat*PI()/180)+COS(city.lat1*PI()/180)*COS(tmp11.lat*PI()/180)*COS(city.lon1*PI()/180-tmp11.lon*PI()/180)))*6372795 as int) between 0 and 60000
```

3.

```
/*insert into clients_res(select clients.pid, clients.owner_id, dist.country, dist.city, dist.distance, clients.inwork  from clients left outer join dist on clients.pid = dist.pid);
 */
```

4.

```
         /*update clients_res 
     set inwork=0
     where distance>0;*/
```

How can i convert it into procedure?

Comment: Have you considered using PostGIS for calculations? You should at least define your own functions for readability

Comment: No, i'm not using PostGIS. I need to do it only by Postgres.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/xplang.html